# Modify test result in @AfterMethod

Tags: java, testing, intellij-idea, testng

I have an issue with TestNG's AfterMethod. I want to modify (fail) test result after method is executed. Following code worked for me at some point, but not anymore. Test result is not changed.

TestNG version is "6.13.1" and I'm using any custom TestNG listeners.

```
@AfterMethod
public void checkTestStatus(ITestContext tc, ITestResult result) {
    if (!result.isSuccess())
        return;

    tc.getPassedTests().removeResult(result.getMethod());

    result.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);
    result.setThrowable(new Exception("Something happened!"));

    tc.getFailedTests().addResult(result, result.getMethod());

    Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(result);
}
```

Comment: ...why are you doing this again?  It seems to unconditionally fail tests.

Comment: It's a simplified test method for demonstration purposes. The problem I have is that tests using this code don't fail for some reason.